# How to use MaxArraySize in BinaryFormatter deserialization in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have done a serialization of a array using BinaryFormatter in C#. It serialize it and crypt and write on disc in less than 2 seconds. However the deserialization will take around 30-40 seconds. Tried also without decryption to ensure it is not the cause of slowness and it makes little to no difference if is on or off.

Through my searches I have found that changing the MaxArraySize should help alot. However I can't find a resource of how to change/use this parameter.

Below is the resource where BinaryFormatter speed and tuning of MaxArraySize param will make a big difference:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/17949#issue-114386886

Comment: "30-40 seconds" is a magic number that doesn't have anything to do with BinaryFormatter.  It is the amount of time typically needed by crummy software when it sees an executable file appearing from seemingly no-where.  Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand your concern. The anti-virus has more than enough time to scan as is a write-file and than user manually loads the same file after a few processes inbetween. I have updated the post by adding the resource found which talks about MaxArraySize and it's tuning implications

Comment: You can also serialize to binary using `MessagePack` and it is very fast.

Comment: @ArjunVachhani Thanks alot. I was lookint right now at it as I have found this documentation which states that is really good https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2017/04/23/the-definitive-serialization-performance-guide/